# tableView endUpdates crashes after change in fetchedResults

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, ios

I have an app which shows a custom no-data-yet cell when the user first launches the app.

When the user makes the first entry the fetchedResults of my fetchedResultsController gets updated, which causes the no-data-yet cell to be deleted and a data cell to be inserted.

this used to work in the past (iPhone 3.x). Now on iOS 4.2, it results in a crash after endUpdates gets called. There is no exception information or any kind of intelligible stack trace. I only know the crash is caused in _CFTypeCollectionRetain (possibly trying to retain a NULL)

Any ideas how to proceed?

here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"starting updates");
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tv = self.tableView;

    [tv reloadData];
    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"insert");

            if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:newIndexPath.section] == 1 &&
                [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 1) 
            {
                NSLog(@"reloading row %d", newIndexPath.row);
                [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"inserting new row %d", newIndexPath.row);
                [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"delete");


            if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:newIndexPath.section] == 0 &&
                [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0) 
            {
                NSLog(@"reloading row %d", newIndexPath.row);
                [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"deleting row %d", newIndexPath.row);
                [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }

            break;

    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"finishing updates");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the delegate method

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

you handle insertions and deletions. For insertions `indexPath` is `nil`. And for deletions `newIndexPath` is `nil`. So you are not allowed to access the `newIndexPath` in case of `type== NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete`.

Besides the call to `reloadData` is not necessary here.